# Loop through element of a defined size in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating an animation for my website where I got different divs containing an image and an aside where I put my text describing something related to the image. The aside is a little bit wider than my picture and what happens is that when I hover it, it slides to the right and has his width increased.

When I hover another one the first one goes back to its initial position. So I found a solution that obliged me to naturally loop through all the divs that are not hovered, but the problem now is since every divs (including the one hovered last) is not hovered, they all get the animation (thus creating a visual bug because the aside is placed absolute and behind the image) while i'd like it to be only on the first one.

So I thought I should loop through all the divs that are not hovered AND got a defined sized (the one they got after they are behind shown), but I couldnt get it work, neither did I find a solution to loop through elements with the each function...

Here is my HTML code :

```
        <div class="partenaires-wrapper">

        <img src="http://mylor.fr/mauro/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sharks.png" alt="" width="223" height="138" />
        <div class="partenaires-aside">

        Sed rutrum elementum odio, ut efficitur magna efficitur sit amet. Phasellus posuere eget felis non tempor. Morbi elementum, velit non aliquam suscipit, 
    odio orci viverra felis, sit amet elementum tellus mauris a nunc. 
Aliquam nec nisl eget nunc pulvinar varius commodo id urna. Duis ac sem erat. Pellentesque aliquet posuere justo ac luctus. Aliquam porta placerat blandit.

        </div>
```

and the Javascript part :

```
$(".partenaires-aside").mouseover(function () {
                       $(".partenaires-aside").not(this).each(function () {
                                $(this).delay( 800 ).animate({'width':'24%'}, 500);
                                $(this).animate({'margin-left':'0%'}, 500);
                                $(this).find("p").hide("slow"); 
                        });
                        $(this).animate({'margin-left':'30%'}, 500);
                        $(this).animate({'width':'60%'}, 500);
                        $(this).find("p").show("slow");    
                });
```

I really dont know if made myself clear, but I hope you understood correctly. Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: If you dont mind the hovered element will return when you move the mouse out, you can do that completely in CSS3; this is similar situation with zoom: http://demo.chobits.ch/CSS3/zoomable.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through all `div`s, you can assign a class lets say `hovered` to the div when hovering and when you hover to another `div` then find previosly hovered div using `class=hovered` and remove class with animation. And add `class=hovered` to currently hovering elemnt.

See below code -

```
$(".partenaires-aside").mouseover(function () {
   //find previosly hovered div using $(".hovered")
   $(".hovered").each(function () {
            $(this).delay( 800 ).animate({'width':'24%'}, 500);
            $(this).animate({'margin-left':'0%'}, 500);
            $(this).find("p").hide("slow");
            //remove hovered class
            $(this).removeClass('hovered'); 
    });

    $(this).animate({'margin-left':'30%'}, 500);
    $(this).animate({'width':'60%'}, 500);
    $(this).find("p").show("slow");
    //add hovered class
    $(this).addClass('hovered');     
});
```

Comment: This is working partially because if I keep hovering the same class, the function will call the animation on the previous div hovered as intended but also on the current one because it is looping through the ".hovered" divs. Your solution is really interesting though, I didnt know I could use something like add class in jquery.

Comment: just wrap the whole code in this condition if(!$(this).attr("class").match('hovered')){[wholeCode]} to prevent  repeating animation on already hovered element